# How can I make a short-key in Spyder (Python IDE)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

Can I make a short key, by either creating some keyboard combination or by an actual button click somewhere in the Spyder IDE for making the following actions:

1. clear my console pane
2. clear all variable from Variable Explorer
3. close all open figure

THANKS !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not possible right now. However, it could be in Spyder 5 (to be released next year) by creating a small plugin for it.

That's because that version will give users a much better API to extend and customize Spyder in all sorts of novel ways.